# WiFi an order of magnitude slower than in Windows using ath9k

Tags: networking, wifi, performance

I'm using an AR9485WB-EG wireless card with Ubuntu 22.04 and the transfer speeds are atrocious — everything from 0.3 to 12 Mbps, compared to 30 to 50 Mbps on Windows 7 running on the same hardware and test conditions. That's 3x to 160x faster in Windows...

Meanwhile my phone does 60 Mbps under the same conditions.

It's been tested many times on many days and the results are always consistent. I use an internet speed test service but I make sure that the wired measurements through the same WiFi access point are always a stable 95 Mbps.

The card is using `ath9k`.

Can the card be made to perform properly?

```
sudo dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn
MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
 #3
pmd_set_huge: Cannot satisfy [mem 0xf8000000-0xf8200000] with a huge-page mapping due to MTRR override.
ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000b4ad9c1e (20210730/exresop-66)
ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20210730/dswexec-431)

No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_PDC]

Initialized Arguments for Method [_PDC]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
  Arg0:   00000000aafce792 <Obj>           Buffer(12) 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00

ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU0._PDC due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20210730/psparse-529)
device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
efifb: Ignoring BGRT: unexpected or invalid BMP data
ata2.00: failed to resume link (SControl 30)
ata2.01: failed to resume link (SControl 30)
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000044F (\GPIS) (20210730/utaddress-204)
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\PMIO) (20210730/utaddress-204)
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000057F (\GPIO) (20210730/utaddress-204)
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GP01) (20210730/utaddress-204)
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000057F (\GPIO) (20210730/utaddress-204)
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GP01) (20210730/utaddress-204)
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000057F (\GPIO) (20210730/utaddress-204)
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GP01) (20210730/utaddress-204)
lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
at24 0-0050: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
at24 0-0052: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
kauditd_printk_skb: 29 callbacks suppressed
================================================================================
UBSAN: invalid-load in /build/linux-MLl0vf/linux-5.15.0/net/mac80211/status.c:1164:21
load of value 255 is not a valid value for type '_Bool'
CPU: 3 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/3 Not tainted 5.15.0-33-generic #34-Ubuntu
Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. K55A/K55A, BIOS K55A.204 03/13/2012
Call Trace:
 <IRQ>
 show_stack+0x52/0x58
 dump_stack_lvl+0x4a/0x5f
 dump_stack+0x10/0x12
 ubsan_epilogue+0x9/0x45
 __ubsan_handle_load_invalid_value.cold+0x44/0x49
 ieee80211_tx_status_ext.cold+0x4e/0x5f [mac80211]
 ieee80211_tx_status+0x72/0xa0 [mac80211]
 ath_txq_unlock_complete+0x12d/0x160 [ath9k]
 ath_tx_edma_tasklet+0xef/0x4c0 [ath9k]
 ? del_timer_sync+0x6c/0xb0
 ath9k_tasklet+0x14e/0x290 [ath9k]
 tasklet_action_common.constprop.0+0xc0/0xf0
 tasklet_action+0x22/0x30
 __do_softirq+0xd9/0x2e3
 irq_exit_rcu+0x8c/0xb0
 common_interrupt+0x8a/0xa0
 </IRQ>
 <TASK>
 asm_common_interrupt+0x1e/0x40
RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xd9/0x620
Code: 3d f4 4b 9e 5b e8 07 ae 6c ff 49 89 c7 0f 1f 44 00 00 31 ff e8 58 ba 6c ff 80 7d d0 00 0f 85 5d 01 00 00 fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <45> 85 f6 0f 88 69 01 00 00 4d 63 ee 49 83 fd 09 0f 87 e3 03 00 00
RSP: 0000:ffffaf9e800b7e28 EFLAGS: 00000246
RAX: ffff9d9a56fb0f00 RBX: ffffcf9e7fd80000 RCX: 0000000000000000
RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000004 RDI: 0000000000000000
RBP: ffffaf9e800b7e78 R08: 0000000ecbd14cf1 R09: 0000000000026160
R10: 0000000000000006 R11: 071c71c71c71c71c R12: ffffffffa5cd36c0
R13: 0000000000000002 R14: 0000000000000002 R15: 0000000ecbd14cf1
 ? cpuidle_enter_state+0xc8/0x620
 cpuidle_enter+0x2e/0x40
 cpuidle_idle_call+0x13e/0x1e0
 do_idle+0x83/0xf0
 cpu_startup_entry+0x20/0x30
 start_secondary+0x12a/0x180
 secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xc2/0xcb
 </TASK>
================================================================================
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` output. I also recommend trying kernel 5.18.1

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov It's been added. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Trying a new kernel is a must and then please try updating BIOS - you have a very old version. If both don't help please file a bug report at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Drivers (under network-wireless). Looking at existing bug reports https://bugzilla.kernel.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=ath9k&list_id=1115290 I have to admit that this piece of hw barely works under Linux. You may want to consider replacing the WiFi module if you need to run Linux or buying a new laptop.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thank you for taking a look! That is good advice and good to know. I haven't considered the firmware. Would you say that it's not unlikely to see such problems manifest in Linux and simultaneously not in Windows? Regarding buying a new laptop, this is an old one that I'm reviving, so I'll at most consider swapping out the card if nothing else helps.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Well, I tried updating to 5.18.1 by using the script in https://askubuntu.com/a/1388117/428527 but I only got `A newer kernel version (v5.18.1) was found but the build was not successful` and then the install failed. Not sure if there are more fail-safe ways to try new kernels.

Comment: The problem might have been alleviated by updating to 5.15.0-35. Three mentions of `ath9k` on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/5.15.0-35.36+22.10.1, but unsure how related those changes are. If the results stick I'll accept it as a solution.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov New kernel seems to have worked. If you want to write an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll add an answer.

Comment: Please do it yourself :-) Would be great if you mentioned me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the kernel, in line with Artem S. Tashkinov's suggestion, seems to have solved the issue. Speeds are now 10x faster and on par with Windows.

Updating from 5.15.0-33 to 5.15.0-35 as part of regular Ubuntu updates seems to have fixed the issue.

There are three mentions of `ath9k` on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/5.15.0-35.36+22.10.1, but I'm unsure how related those items are to the problem.